# Advantage of orthogonal polynomials

Tags: multiple-regression, total-least-squares, orthogonal

What is the sense or background of orthogonal polynomials (regarding using mixed models)? I would like to know why they shall or should be orthogonal. Is it to build independent sample points?
On [Is there ever a reason not to use orthogonal polynomials when fitting regressions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104085/is-there-ever-a-reason-not-to-use-orthogonal-polynomials-when-fitting-regression) I found a related discussion but either they didn't point it out or I just don't recognize it.

Comment: check my answer here. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233414/why-are-there-large-coefficents-for-higher-order-polynomial/234196#234196

Comment: Thank you! I read a bit more in paralell so sorry that I didn't answer before. Can you please explain me why orthogonal polynomials do not change its lower coefficients? How do they know when they are "allowed" to affect?